# Cassandra Counters Double Counting

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am new to Cassandra and am having an issue with counters double counting sometimes.  I am trying to keep track of daily event counts for certain events.  Here is my table structure:

```
create table pipes.pipe_event_counts (
    count counter,
    pipe_id text,
    event_type text,
    date text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((pipe_id, event_type, date))
);
```

The driver I am using is the Datastax Java driver, and I am compiling and binding parameters to the following prepared statement:

```
incrementPipeEventCountStatement =  CassandraClient.getInstance().getSession().prepare(
    QueryBuilder.update("pipes", PIPE_EVENT_COUNT_TABLE_NAME).with(incr("count")).
    where(eq("pipe_id", "?")).and(eq("date", "?")).and(eq("event_type", "?")).
    getQueryString()
);

incrementPipeEventCountStatement.bind(
    event.getAttrubution(Meta.PIPE_ID), dateString, event.getType().toString()
)
```

The problem is very weird.  Sometimes when I process a single event, the counter increments properly by 1.  However, the majority of the time, it double increments.  I've been looking at my code for some time now and can't find any issues that would cause a second increment.

Is my implementation of counters in Cassandra correct for my use case? I think it is, but I could be losing my mind.  I'm hoping someone can help me confirm so I can focus in the right area to find my problem.

**Important edit:**  This is the query I'm running to check the count after the event:

```
select count from pipes.pipe_event_counts where pipe_id = 'homepage' and event_type = 'click' and date = '2015-04-07';
```

Comment: what version of cassandra? http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters

Comment: I'm using 2.1.  Thanks for the link - I'll check it out.

Comment: I still haven't figured out what's causing this, but it's only an issue in my dev environment.  I'm using the Play Framework to host the app, and it's in dev mode locally (as expected).  It's probably related to that.  In either case, not a production issue, so I'll ignore it for now.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with counters is that they are **not idempotent operations** so when you retry (and don't know if your original write was successful) you may end up over-counting.

You can also never re-try and undercount.

As Chris chared, there are some issues with the counter implementation [pre-2.1](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters) that make the overcounting issue much more severe. There are also performance issues associated with counters so you want to make sure you look into these in detail before you push a counter deployment to production.

Here are the related Jiras to help you make informed decisions:

Counters ++ (major improvement - fixed 2.1) -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6504

Memory / GC issues from large counter workloads, Counter Column (major improvement - fixed 2.1)--https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6405

Counters into separate cells (final solution - eta 3.1)- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6506